# How to interprete python function's parameter in its documents?

Tags: python

For example:

class multiprocessing.pool 's function:

```
apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])
```

What are the square brackets mean?
In the following code, when using function `apply_async`, why `args=(i,)` if `args=i`, then it cann't work.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from  multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import random
import time

def appear(name):
    print("{0} running {1} task".format(name, os.getpid()))
    start=time.time()
    time.sleep(random.random() * 3)
    end=time.time()
    print("{0} running for {1} seconds".format(name, (end - start)))

def f(a):
    return a * a

p=Pool()

for i in range(5):
    p.apply_async(appear, args=(i,))

print("waiting for all subprocess done..")
p.close()
p.join()
print("all done")
```

The Python's module functions have many parameters. It's really hard to understand them.

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets just mean the arguments are *optional*. You can call the method without specifying the arguments in brackets.

The documentation points to the [`apply()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply); you want to read the documentation for that function too. It explains what the different arguments mean; like `args` for instance:

> the *args* argument must be a sequence.

`args=i` would not be a sequence, while `args=(i,)` would be; `(i,)` is a one-element tuple, and a tuple is a sequence.